# base_link to laser frame

Tags: laser, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to use gmapping, RVIZ, etc. I wrote a urdf file to describe my robot.
I have a problem with transform. I have to provide a base_link to laser_frame transform.
Should I write this transform or does it already exist in hokuyo node ?
If I have to write if, do I need to transform every points of the laser scan ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11533/base_link-to-laser-frame/) by [elfugao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1215/elfugao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The transform should be in your URDF file. You should have a link base_link that is your base and a hokuyo link that is the laser_frame.
You use a robot state publisher that will send out these transforms automatically from the URDF.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-02**:
I wrote a tf_broadcaster to send transform between base_link and laser and also tried tf's static_transform_publisher. Is this okay?

Because when I launch rviz, I cannot visualize the laser scan with base_footprint or base_link as the fixed frame although tf view_frames shows everything correctly.